# I am trying to add a number to a variable name 'X' to get (X1, X2 etc) in a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, csv, for-loop, append

I have a CSV table that i am able to read from, i have to do certain calculations from the columns of that table, what i am trying to do is read each column separately and split it to get the actual numbers to avoid the column name.

For example:

```
C1 = []
C2 = []
for line in data:
    C1.append(line.split(",")[0])
    C2.append(line.split(",")[1])

print  C1
print  C2
```

I am trying to come up with a for loop that can change the variable C to C1, C2 etc based on a certain number, so if i have 4 columns the for loop would do this

```
C1.append(line.split(",")[0])
C2.append(line.split(",")[1])
C3.append(line.split(",")[2])
C2.append(line.split(",")[3])
```

How can I add a number to the variable name C and use that in a for loop?

Comment: What is wrong with a list of lists instead of lists C1, C2...?

Comment: What i am trying to do is to give each column a different name so that i can use them later to do some calculations, if there is a better way to do this please share.

Comment: There are myriad better ways to do this.  However, your question really does not discuss what you trying to do.  We call this the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).